# What's the best way (word or phrase) to say "out of pattern"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

Person 1: [Flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com/) sends the ordered materials to your home via post within 2-3 business days.

Person 2: Meh, I have seen them being late; one of my friends got his ordered material after 10 days!!

Person 1: I would say that is a *out of pattern* case!

So what is the best way to say "out of pattern" here? I want to mean a "discreet" occurence i.e. which does not usually occur. "Discreet" is the word I use in my mother tongue in this case. Can it mean the same in English too?

Answer (score 3):

Given your context, I would say:

> That's not the norm.

NOAD defines *norm* as "something that is usual, typical, or standard".

You might also word it as:

> Well, that's an exception.

Other words you could consider are *aberration* or *atypical*, as in "That sounds like an aberration," or "That seems like an atypical case to me."

Comment: When I read the question, one of my first thoughts (before I saw your answer) was “that’s an [or ***the***] exception rather than the rule.” Another option: “that’s an outlier;” but I am a mathematician, and that’s somewhat of a mathematical term. I don’t know how commonly used (or even well known) it is among non-mathematicians.

Comment: @Scott - I like _outlier_ quite a bit, but I'd probably avoid using that unless I knew that my audience had a fairly strong background in mathematics and/or statistics. In the right place, at the right time, though, it's a very apt word.

Answer (score 2):

A phrase with a structure similar to "*out of the pattern*":

> That's ***out of the ordinary***.

Answer (score 2):

> Person 2: Meh, I have seen them being late; one of my friends got his ordered material after 10 days!!
>
> Person 1: I would say that was **[the exception rather than the rule](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20exception%20rather%20than%20the%20rule).**

Merriam-Webster defines the idiom as: “*not common or usual :  not often done, seen, or happening :  rare*”

For something a little more colloquial, you can say

- that was a **[once in a blue moon](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/once-in-a-blue-moon.html)** episode.

Answer (score 1):

You can say **unusual**, e.g., ***"That's an unusual case"***. But it might be enough just to say *"That's unusual"*. Another word is ***atypical***, but it might be more suitable in writing.

By the way, I take it that you meant *discrete*, not *discreet*.

Comment: I don't think _ridiculous_ and _absurd_ are good words to use in this case, not unless the speaker is not only expressing surprise, but also challenging the claim that the package arrived that late. The word _unbelievable_ also expresses some disbelief – _unsual_ and _atypical_ are commenting on an observed exception rather than expressing incredulity at the claim.

Comment: Agreed. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use *out of pattern* because it doesn't really sound idiomatic to me. In the context provided, I'd say,

> *That's a bit unusual.*
>
> *That's a bit odd.*

Or something along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

If it's merely a small deviation from the pattern,

> That's irregular.
>
> That's an irregular behavior.

is a semi-formal (in formal contexts - just standard, in informal contexts - humorous) way of phrasing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

1. This is not the usual case.
2. This is out of the ordinary.
3. This is an atypical case.
4. This is a nonstandard case.

However, I would stick to "**abnormal**" as in "*This is an **abnormal** case.*".

> Something that is abnormal is out of the ordinary, or not typical. Abnormal is a combination of the Latin prefix ab which means “away from,” and the English word normal. It essentially means “not normal,” or "unusual.” Abnormal implies that whatever is “not normal” is also undesirable.